# Possible to have XSLT compute a string as a math function? It includes +s and *s

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xslt

I am dynamically building an XSLT string including plus signs and multplication signs using concat. I.e.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' + ', number(@amount))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' * ', number(@gc_own))"/>
```

Is it possible to tell XSLT to compute it?  I.e., I have a string `-864963 * 0.0963 + 269048 * 0.09 + -22052 * 0.002 + 18777687 * 0.2 + -132428 * 0.096 + 0 * 0.3 + -2813 * 0.0966 + -96 * 0.25 + -1081 * 0.0001 + -456 * 0.001 + 53473 * 0.0044 + -580298 * 0.1`
?

Can I have XSLT compute the result all at once? Or do I need to store each value as a number variable and add them together?

EDIT: I didn't think to mention that operator precedence was important

Comment: Why build a string, when you can build a result? Or both, if you want a "calculator paper tape" type of result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="string" select="'-864963 * 0.0963 + 269048 * 0.09 + -22052 * 0.002 + 18777687 * 0.2 + -132428 * 0.096 + 0 * 0.3 + -2813 * 0.0966 + -96 * 0.25 + -1081 * 0.0001 + -456 * 0.001 + 53473 * 0.0044 + -580298 * 0.1'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="calculate">
            <xsl:with-param name="formula" select="concat('+ ', normalize-space($string), ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="calculate">
    <xsl:param name="formula"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$formula">
            <xsl:variable name="operator" select="substring($formula, 1, 1)" />
            <xsl:variable name="operand" select="substring-before(substring-after($formula, ' '), ' ')" />
            <xsl:variable name="nextFormula" select="substring-after(substring-after($formula, ' '), ' ')" />
            <xsl:variable name="nextResult">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$operator = '+'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$result + $operand"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$operator = '*'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$result * $operand"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="calculate">
                <xsl:with-param name="formula" select="$nextFormula"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="result" select="number($nextResult)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

> if only this maintained operator precedence

As a proof of concept, this solution relies on EXSLT to tokenize the string, rather than on a named template. The order of operations is as follows:

step 1: get all expressions contained between + signs;
step 2: multiply the factors contained in these expressions;
step 3: sum the resulting products.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="string" select="'-2 * 3 + 4 * 5 + -6 * 7'" />

<xsl:variable name="products">
    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate($string, ' ', ''), '+')" >
        <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
            <xsl:with-param name="factors" select="str:tokenize(., '*')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($products)/product)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="multiply">
    <xsl:param name="factors"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($factors)">
            <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
                <xsl:with-param name="factors" select="$factors[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="result" select="$result * $factors[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <product><xsl:value-of select="$result"/></product>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That solution assumes there is no operator precedence, I think? Who knows what the real requirement is...

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, that is very true. I assumed the given string was a sequence of calculator key-presses, so to speak. But I now see that it can also be read as a sequence of multiplications added together.

Comment: Upvoted. Would mark as answer if only this maintained operator precedence

Comment: @Hoppe I suppose you could tokenize on the + signs, multiply the contents and then add up the tokens. Not sure if it's worth the effort, though - I suspect a better solution can be founds upstream.

Comment: Is the edit a working example? I can't seem to get it to run in visual studio's xsl engine, xml spy, or by executing the xsl via c#

Comment: @Hoppe It does work, but only with processors that support the EXSLT str:tokenize() function (basically libxslt and Xalan). To make it work with other processors, you need to use a named template to tokenize the string instead of the function. Try: http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the semantics of your expression are the same as the XPath semantics, you can use any xx:evaluate() extension available in your processor. Some processors support such an extension function, Saxon supports the XSLT 3.0 xsl:evaluate instruction.

Comment: what syntax would I use? I'm not sure what the xx. refers to

Comment: Many processors have implemented some kind of evaluate() extension in their own namespace. If you tell us what XSLT processor you are using then we can be more specific.

Comment: I'm using c# 4.0's System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Xsl.Transform() method. It looks like it only supports the XSLT 1.0 specification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126k9kx5(v=vs.100).aspx. Does that provide you the info?

Comment: I'm no expert on that processor. As far as I know it doesn't offer an xx:evaluate extension, but it probably allows you to write your own. In the .NET environment you could use Saxon which provides the XSLT 3.0 xsl:evaluate instruction.